# How to do chrome debugging?

Tags: debugging, mobile

I have developed a website. Some clients are getting the issue on chrome while opening a website. It's working on other search engines like firefox etc. How should I debug it in inspect mode(how to take his/her MOBILE(only) )on support? I know one solution which USB debugging but we can't take clients phone and do debugging. Is there any solution so that we can take his/her phone on inspect mode remotely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that you can try is trying to plug error tracker on your website.

One of them is Sentry https://sentry.io (Its free, but if you want to use it with more volume and features, you have to pay for it.)

The way it works is you put sentry `raven.js` on your html head block

```
<script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.24.2/raven.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and then configure it by attaching the sentry api key (you can look at their documentation as well, they provide you with some code examples https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/).

And after you can ask the client to browse your website using their device. By default sentry will track their session and show it in your sentry dashboard, including all of the javascript error and console output (just like when you do when you open inspect mode in your web browser). so you can try to debug the problem without having to take your client device.